# gumbo-d bindings with DUB

Tags: d, gumbo, dub

I'm trying to use gumbo-d in a project however dub is failing.

Here's the dub output:

```
Building: myproject (Default)
Performing main compilation...
dub build "myproject" "--build=plain"
Building package myproject in C:\Users\Matt\Documents\Projects\myproject\
Target vibe-d 0.7.23 is up to date. Use --force to rebuild.
Target gumbo-d 0.2.2 is up to date. Use --force to rebuild.
Building myproject ~master configuration "application", build type plain.
Compiling using dmd...
Linking...

OPTLINK (R) for Win32  Release 8.00.15
Copyright (C) Digital Mars 1989-2013  All rights reserved.
http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/optlink.html
..\..\..\AppData\Roaming\dub\packages\gumbo-d-0.2.2\gumbo-d.lib(parse) 
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _gumbo_destroy_output
..\..\..\AppData\Roaming\dub\packages\gumbo-d-0.2.2\gumbo-d.lib(parse) 
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _gumbo_parse
--- errorlevel 2
FAIL .dub\build\application-plain-windows-x86-dmd_2066-946D41E793C045166B4DFD37035481AE\ myproject executable
Error executing command build: dmd failed with exit code 2.

Exit code 2
Build complete -- 1 error, 0 warnings

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Build: 1 error, 0 warnings
```

I'm at a bit of a loss of where the library file needs to go and what format it needs to be in.  There is a .lib file in the gumbo-d dependency directory, is this meant to be the library?  If so, why is the linker failing to link to it?

Here is the contents of my main dub.json file (for the overall project which includes the gumbo-d dependency)

```
{
    "name": "googleplayscraper",
    "description": "A simple vibe.d server application.",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2015, Matt",
    "authors": ["Matt"],
    "dependencies": {
        "vibe-d": "~>0.7.19",
        "gumbo-d": "~>0.2.2"
    },
    "versions": ["VibeDefaultMain"]
}
```

And here is the dub.json file for the gumbo-d dependency:

```
{
    "libs-posix": [
        "gumbo"
    ],
    "version": "0.2.2",
    "description": "D bindings for Google's Gumbo HTML5 parser library",
    "authors": [
        "Christopher Bertels"
    ],
    "importPaths": [
        "source/"
    ],
    "configurations": [
        {
            "targetType": "library",
            "name": "library"
        }
    ],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/bakkdoor/gumbo-d",
    "sourcePaths": [
        "source/"
    ],
    "name": "gumbo-d",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2013, Christopher Bertels"
}
```

Comment: I tried gumbo-d binding, but in result I decided that it's much easier to use Adam's dom.d parser. It's _very_ easy, and you can find a lot examples of it's usega on forum.dlang.org 
https://github.com/adamdruppe/arsd

Comment: Great , Adam's dom.d parser is excellent.  Perfect for what I need.  Lightweight with a great interface.